# How to place two Fivestar widgets on the node for voting?

Tags: rating

I would like to place the fivestar voting widget both to the beginning and to the end of my node. I do not talk about two different ratings, I'd like to let my readers vote in both positions. I read the code of Fivestar, but I did not find the solution in the module source. I think the JS code would get wrong if two voting widgets were present on the page.
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem, how to duplicate the voting widget somehow..?

I'm using Drupal 6 btw and Fivestar 1.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a PHP code like this

```
$node=node_load($nid);
print fivestar_widget_form($node);
```

the forms will have different ids so the javascript will work

you have to create a custom php/tpl file for this node-CONENENTTYPENAME.tpl.php by copying the contents of your node.tpl.php  and include there the custom code...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/node/1862908) and enable the node_view template and set the fivestar field twice or even more wherever you'd like it to go.